# Heckman selection with Ordered logit as a second stage in R

Tags: r

I am using the library(sampleSelection) to run an Heckman selection model. However, my main outcome variable is not continuous but an ordered categorical variable (5 ordered cat.). Thus, I am wondering whether the package support an ordered logistic regression as second stage outcome regression. Do you have some suggestions? Is there a different package?
I think in Stata  a similar model is implemented with the code heckoprobit.
Thank you very much in advance.

Ps. I cannot create better tags, for this question I think you could add sampleSelection, Heckman, heckoprobit.

````
library(sampleSelection) 
#data are D1
summary(ml_fit2 <- heckit(
  selection = `Use_S` ~  Age  + Female+Foreign+Perception ,
  outcome = Y ~  X1 +X2 +X3,
  method = "ml",  data = D1))```
````

Comment: Stata not being free is absolutely correct, but a user of Stata can view the code for `heckoprobit` so it's more open there than you're implying.  Either way, the Stata tag is a distraction here as you seek only R details, so I have edited it out.

Comment: Quite why Stata doesn't offer this for ordered logit -- which is what you ask for -- is a serious detail I can't address helpfully.

Comment: Thank you @NickCox , you are right. This was my attempt to explain the issue by making a parallel with STATA. Many R users use both. Could you add the tag for the sampleSelection R package. Apparently I cannot..

Comment: You need a reputation of 1500 to create new tags. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges I will let R people reading this decide whether such a tag is a good idea. I don't think a tag for each distinct R package is a good idea at all, but it's up to others.

Comment: Ok @NickCox thanks for the clarification. Would you suggest a better tag for my question?

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to try to answer at all. I noticed your question because you added a Stata tag, but neither R nor this kind of modelling is an area of my expertise. You have the wonderful R community to look to.